# Can't access my PDO connection in my class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I have the following code  in a class :

```
function __construct(&$User, &$db, $DeptId=0) {
//Will contruct the class
    $this->ID = $DeptId;
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->User = $User;
    $this->Update();
}
```

The "**$db**" I pass in the object is a PDO connection that I got this way :

```
$dns = "mysql:host=". DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME.';charset=utf8';
$utilisateur = DBUSER;
$motDePasse = DBPW;
$DbLink = new PDO( $dns, $utilisateur, $motDePasse );  
$DbLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

And I call the class this way :

```
$dept = new cl_dept($user,$DbLink);
```

Now for my problem, in my class, I have a simple function to add a column in a table if it doesn't exist (In case there's a version upgrade)

```
private function Update() {
   $queryPrep = $this->db->prepare('ALTER IGNORE TABLE ko_depts ADD dp_enabled boolean(true)');
   $queryPrep->execute();
}
```

But everytime I run the function I get FATAL Error on the execute commande from my query :

*Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/daniel/public_html/komando/include/table_class.php on line 32*

I've tried the SQL on it own and got a error.  So could it be that the PDO is not working because of a SQL error? If so, how could I display the error message?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($db)` in the `__construct()` method to see what the `$db` parameter contains?

Comment: I get =>   object(PDO)#2 (0) { }

Comment: I've change my SQL for "SELECT * FROM ko_depts", so there a error in my SQL statement. does anyone have a clue?

Comment: `catch` PDO errors or check `$this->db->errorInfo()` to see what's going on...